# Mapstruct is not updating its getters and setters in the generated source files

Tags: java, spring, lombok, mapstruct

I have an entity with a property I used to write like this
private Long ICU;

I'm using mapstruct:

Here is my mapper for said entity:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProtectionQueryMapper extends EntityMapper<ProtectionQueryDto, Protection> {

    ProtectionQueryDto toDto(Protection protection);

    Protection toEntity(ProtectionQueryDto protectionQueryDto);

    List<Protection> toEntity(List<ProtectionQueryDto> protectionQueryDtos);

    List<ProtectionQueryDto> toDto(List<Protection> protections);

}
```

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {

    E toEntity(D dto);

    D toDto(E entity);

    List<E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);

    List<D> toDto(List<E> entityList);
}
```

The problem I have is that I want to change the property from ICU go icu, which I did and it resulted in this error:

> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>
> Protection.getICU()Ljava/lang/Long;

It would seem that mapstruct generated its getters and setters based on:
`private Long ICU;`
generating method like setICU and getICU.
But now that I have changed the property from ICU to icu mapstruct is not updating its method to `setIcu` and `getIcu`.

I cannot change the `mapstruct` generated file manually.

Also here is my pom.xml (at least the part regarding mapstruct)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>  
  <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</arg>
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Any idea how to have mapstruct update its generated source file?

Comment: Are you using Maven to build the project?

Comment: Yes I am. I will add my pom.xml in my question.

Comment: I guess you've tried `mvn clean compile`?

Comment: You could always add the `@Mapping` annotations for all non trivial mappings like `@Mapping(source = "icu", target = "ICU")` but this seems wrong... MapStruct should be case insensitive in such situation :/

Comment: try `mvn clean install`, mapper implementation classes are placed in target folder and they won't be updated unless you `mvn clean` your project resulting in removal of target folder

Comment: @burubum : running mvn clean compile seems to have fixed the issue, thanks.

Comment: Do you use Lombok for your entities and DTOs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason the recompile of the project didn't run the annotation processor. MapStruct is invoked by the Java compiler and the maven-compiler-plugin is responsible for cleaning up the folder with the generated classes.

Doing `mvn clean compile` will always work. However, if doing a change and then doing `mvn compile` doesn't, I would try with the latest version of the maven-compiler-plugin and if that still doesn't work create a bug report for the plugin.

Answer (score 15):

You need to provide the **lombok** plugin first in order, then the **mapstruct-processor** plugin just like this.

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So simple yet so important. Thank you. You saved me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10467757/adil-aslam-sachwani for his answer about setting mapstruct processor after lombok's one. It worked for me, but I have it with gradle, so in that case, it should be like this:

```
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.2.Final'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.2.Final'
```

Comment: This worked for me after putting the mapstruct and lombok in correct order. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lombok for your entities and DTOs you have to update your pom.xml like this:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then Mupstruct will be able to see their getters and setters.

(You can check my [project](https://github.com/Cepr0/generic-crud) and its [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/generic-crud/tree/master/demo) to see this in action.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but after editing your pom.xml like Dan Dragut, and if you use intellij, try clicking on the hammer that is located on the left side of the "run" button, that will cause the project to be rebuilt, then your generated sources will be up to date again

Comment: The toolbar icons in IntelliJ and other IDEs can be customized, so please provide better description how to find the rebuild button or you can just suggest to use the rebuild functionality.