# How to map native query result to POJO?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a complex sql query that joins 7 tables and returns 110 columns. I am trying to use native query created using shared entity manager. Not sure how to map the resultset to a POJO. Mapping each column to resultset object array works, but is very inefficient in terms of lines of code. Any suggestion how to map it or any other way I can perform this?

Here's some pseudo code I have implemented:

```
Query query = sharedEntityManager.createNativeQuery(
                 " select a.c1, a.c2,.., b.c1, b.c2,.., c.c1, c.c2,...
                   from atab a, btab b, ctab c, ...
                   where condition1, condition2,...");

query.setParameter("param1", param1);

List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

List<CustomPojo> retList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object[] obj : results){
  CustomPojo row = new CustomPojo();
  row.setF1(obj[0].toString());
  row.setF2(obj[1].toString());
  ...
  ...
  retList.add(row);
}
return retList;
```

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Data JPA (and we can assume that because you added that tag), then simply add the query to one of your Repository interface:

```
public interface WhateverRepository extends JpaRepository<...,...>

  ...

  @Query(SELECT NEW com.yourcompany...YourPOJO a.c1, a.c2,.., b.c1, b.c2,.., c.c1, c.c2,...
               from atab a, btab b, ctab c, ...
               where condition1, condition2,...")
  YourPOJO callFancyQuery( arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Spring Data JPA will do the rest.
(You can refer to the arguments in your query by their name: `:arg1`, `:arg2`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DTO, you can easily use [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) with **native queries** in Spring Data JPA, for example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "models")
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String name;
}
```

Projection:

```java
public interface NameOnly {
     String getName();
}
```

Repo:

```java
public interface ModelRepo extends JpaRepository<Model, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select m.name as name from models m", nativeQuery = true)
    List<NameOnly> getAll();
}
```

(Notice the need to use aliases in the query: `m.name as name`.)

If you really need DTO, then you can create, for example, a mapper (I believe it's better to generate it with [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) in your case):

```java
@Data
public class ModelDto {
    private String name;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ModelMapper {
    ModelDto toDto(NameOnly nameOnly);
}
```

Then use it something like that:

```java
@Autowired private ModelRepo repo;
@Autowired private ModelMapper mapper;
// ...
repo.getAll()
    .stream()
    .map(mapper::toDto)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- [More examples from SDJPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java)
- [MapStruct and Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890896/5380322)